# How to paginate laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

Hei I got some problem with pagination so I use to be make pagination with this simple code

```
$posts = Auth::user()->posts()->latest()->paginate(5);
```

and it will paginate automatically

but when I use code like this

```
$count = $this->getCountPost()->paginate(5);
```

it will retrieve error

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.

this is my getcountpost function

```
private function getCountPost(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $posts = $user->posts;
    foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
        $posts[$key]->comment_to_post = Post::where('id_post', $value->id)->count();
    }
    return $posts;
```

hope you can help me guys

Comment: `$posts` is an Eloquent Collection. Paginate works on the Query Builder, I believe.

Comment: [`paginate`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_paginate) is a function on [QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html), it is not available on Laravel Collections.

Comment: so how to fix it guys ?

Comment: Use this link may help for using pagination on collection data. https://gist.github.com/vluzrmos/3ce756322702331fdf2bf414fea27bcb

Comment: Try to pick things up from here if you're using zurb or want to add your custom pagination component: https://github.com/belthaZornv/zurb-foundation-laravel-pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this there are several approaches avalable.

## Method 1:

For paginating a collection, Laravel provides a method called `forPage`

https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_forPage

Try the following method and may be this is what you're looking for.

```
return $this->getCountPost()->forPage(1, 10);
```

For this scenario, you'll have to buld your own logic to add the links to paginate.

however, the following approach will make life more easier.

## Method 2:

Using Laravel's `LengthAwarePaginator`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
 
use App\Http\Requests;
 
class ItemsController extends Controller
{
     public function items(Request $request)
    {
        $items = [
            'item1',
            'item2',
            'item3',
            'item4',
            'item5',
            'item6',
            'item7',
            'item8',
            'item9',
            'item10'
            ];
 
        // Get current page form url e.x. &page=1
        $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();
 
        // Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
        $itemCollection = collect($items);
 
        // Define how many items we want to be visible in each page
        $perPage = 1;
 
        // Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
        $currentPageItems = $itemCollection->slice(($currentPage * $perPage) - $perPage, $perPage)->all();
 
        // Create our paginator and pass it to the view
        $paginatedItems= new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems , count($itemCollection), $perPage);
 
        // set url path for generted links
        $paginatedItems->setPath($request->url());
 
        return view('items_view', ['items' => $paginatedItems]);
    }
```

And on the blade file

```
 <h1>Items List</h1>
 
<ul>
@foreach ($items as $item) 
   <li> {{ $item }} </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
 
<div>
{{ $items->links() }}
</div>
```

Reference: https://arjunphp.com/laravel-5-pagination-array/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a helper function on your `Post` model to count what you wanted to count on each post.

```
public function getCommentsToPostCount($id)
{
    return Post::where('id_post', $id)->count();
} // this is an alternative for your `for` loop.
```

And then, let's update your `getCountPost`

```
private function getCountPost(){
    return Auth::user()->posts();
}
```

Now on your usage, you can now:

```
$pages = $this->getCountPost()->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

the $post variable contains the total no of page count and you can use like this `$post->total`